# Why does AWS CloudWatch dashboard widget does not respect scales when drawing two lines?

Tags: charts, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm new to AWS and CloudWatch.
Here is a screenshot of a CloudWatch dashboard showing two parameters related to a Dynamo table.

[image]

As you can see in the pop-up the value of the sample for the orange timeseries is 2,252 while the value of the sample for the red timeseries is 7,000, yet the red chart is drawn under the orange chart. If you check the scale on the left, it seems the red series is the one that get drawn correctly, while the line of the orange one is somehow "inflated".

Can you please help me understand what is the reason behind this?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your mouse hover point data and the popup data are out of sync. Just a UI glitch.

The popup is showing 09:57 and probably on the chart at 09:57 those are the correct values.

The hover point you chose is a particular peak and is at what time? The last digit is cut off from the display but it's definitely not a 7! Looks like "09:50" maybe?

Minor UI glitch is my diagnosis.

Comment: Thx @hunterhacker, could be indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I come up with this different set up, where one of the series has values mapped on the left Y-axis, while the other series has values mapped on the right Y-axis.

[image]

The main drawback is that the two series are not directly comparable, but at least the difference in value is more evident.